# SQL: Find Sessions that contain each of several pages

Tags: sql

I have a database which contains sessionid's and pagenames.  I'd like to get a list of the sessionid's where the user went to all 4 of the 'Cart','UserInfo','Checkout' and 'Confirm' pages.

Let's pretend our table is like this:

```
Sessionid, PageName
939j     , Home
9d3k     , Login
e9se     , Cart
efw0     , Checkout
e9se     , UserInfo
```

etc...

Any suggestions on how to do something like this ?

Comment: You should tag your sql-variant i.e. database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
select sessionid
from t
group by sessionid
having count(distinct pagename) = 4
```

The above assumes that the four page names you mentioned are the only ones.  If there are others, then filter before aggregating:

```
select sessionid
from t
where pagename in ('Cart','UserInfo','Checkout', 'Confirm')
group by sessionid
having count(distinct pagename) = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'Cart','UserInfo','Checkout' and 'Confirm' are all the distinct pagenames in the table then group by sessionid and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT sessionid
FROM tablename
GROUP BY sessionid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pagename) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pagename) FROM tablename)
```